# When retrieving url stored in firebase database it is crashing app giving error Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.net.Uri

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added imageUrl in firebase database and when i try to retrieve that url app is crashing.
Here is my Event listener code:

```
DatabaseReference valueRef = myRef.child("Users").child(name);
                valueRef.child("ProfileUrl").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        photoUrl= dataSnapshot.getValue(Uri.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Error is in 5th line where photoUrl is used.

I have defined myRef = database.getReference();
and also listed photoUrl as Uri. But it still says cannot convert string to uri. I dont understand when everything is in uri where did string come from?

Firebase Database Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try changing your code inside of onDataChange(...) to:
photoUrl= Uri.parse((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());

Comment: Now App is not crashing but still i cannot retrive my url that is in database as shown in screenshot. Basically i want to get that ProfileUrl. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of photoUrl when onDataChanged gets fired? Try printing it out with log cat.

Comment: How to print it with logcat?

Comment: You use the Android logging API.

Comment: How can i do that? Little new to android world. Sorry

Comment: I think you should pause whatever project you are working on and learn some basics about Android development. The Log class is a very basic framework class to log messages to the Android console. View the source here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log

Comment: you can use  `String url = dataSnapshot.getValue("ProfileUrl")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get it as a String first and then parse to URI. The URI class is a lot more than simply the URL string, that's why you're getting a can't cast error. What you have in your database is a string representing an URL.

```
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      photoUrl=  Uri.parse( url );
      Log.d("PHOTOURL", photoUrl.toString());
 }
```

If you want to use photoUrl outside of the onDataChande function you need to call a method or write your usage code inside onDataChange:

```
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      photoUrl=  Uri.parse( url );
      usePhotoUrl();
 }
```

Then use it in the method:

```
 public void usePhotoUrl(){
   //you can use phootUrl here
 }
```

Comment: Now App is not crashing but still i cannot retrive my url that is in database as shown in screenshot. Basically i want to get that ProfileUrl. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you receiving onDataChange? does it get fired? What's the value of the variable url?

Comment: It gets fired. Value of url? i need my database url value in photoUrl and is there any way to check at compilation whether i am getting that value or not?

Comment: You can add a Log statement aftewards, but I think I know what might be happening. You're trying to use photoUrl before it's been received. All work over the photoUrl variable needs to be done after it's been filled by the callback, so either inside the onDataChange method or in another method that is called inside onDataChange. Check the edit

Comment: To check that the photoUrl variable is being filled just add the Log.d statement, check the edit. To see if you're reciving the correct value check the logcat in android studion usually it will opened with (ctrl+6). Search for PHOTOURL

Comment: Thanks Mate you are the life savious i know its stupid thing but i didnt know about that if we want to use variables we need to do it within onDataChange Class. Wish i can give more upvotes to you.

Comment: this is due to the async nature of firebase callbacks. it's very common we forget that :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :)

```
String url = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
photoUri = Uri.parse(url);
```

Comment: Now App is not crashing but still i cannot retrive my url that is in database as shown in screenshot. Basically i want to get that ProfileUrl. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you using your URI?

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference valueRef = myRef.child("Users").child(name);
valueRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Uri photoUrl= Uri.parse(dataSnapshot.child("ProfileUrl").getValue().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Now App is not crashing but still i cannot retrive my url that is in database as shown in screenshot. Basically i want to get that ProfileUrl. Any suggestions?

Comment: How can i check whether my photoUrl is even taking that database url or not?

Comment: Yes I did it gives error that Object cannot be converted to string but still didnt able to get the desired result. I want Database url in my photoUrl.

Comment: I have updated the code. This will surely do your work.

Comment: App is crashing now giving error "'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference"